# Combining subselects in SQL query

Tags: sql-server

How can I simplify this query by combining the subselects?

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE id1 IN (SELECT id1 FROM table WHERE [keyid] = 123)
  AND id2 IN (SELECT [id2] FROM table WHERE [keyid] = 123)
```

I naively tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE id1 = t.id1 
  AND id2 = t.id2
   IN (SELECT id1, id2 FROM table WHERE keyid = 123) AS t
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your tablenames, I assume that both IN Clauses refer to same table and refer to same key field.

```
SELECT t1.* FROM Table AS t1
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT Id1, Id2 FROM Table WHERE keyid = 123
) as t2
ON t1.id1 = t2.id1 AND t1.id2 = t2.id2
```

Comment: Note that your answer has changed the logic here.  Now, you only retain records should there be a single record where _both_ `id1` and `id2` happen to have `keyid = 123` at the same time.  The original query just requires that this happens separately.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, got it. I have updated my assumption. I assumed that both are referring to same keyfield and from same table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I think my assumption is correct, as OP has mentioned that both columns are coming from same table against keyfield = 123

Comment: If your answer is correct, then the OP wrote the wrong logic in the initial query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Yes. agree with you.

Comment: My pseudo code was meant to get id1 and Id2 from the row containing the unique keyid and then to get all rows that contain BOTH id1 and id2. Basically, think of the keyid as identifying an individual and id1 and id2 as the parents. The result would be a list of siblings. In any case the posted code seems to work just fine and is more elegant than mine. Thank you all.

Comment: @ihf, mark the answer helped you, so it will be helpful for others in future. If some answer helped you also, upvote them

Answer (score 5):

There is no real need to rewrite your query, it is fine as-is.  You could rewrite the subqueries using exists logic:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t2.id1 = t1.id1 AND t2.keyid = 123) AND
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t3 WHERE t3.id2 = t1.id2 AND t3.keyid = 123);
```

The exists logic would let SQL Server stop scanning your table as soon as it finds a single match.  This might mean improved performance over the version you currently have.

If you wanted to rewrite using a series of self joins, here is what you could try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2 ON t2.id1 = t1.id1
INNER JOIN yourTable t3 ON t3.id2 = t1.id2
WHERE t2.keyid = 123 AND t3.keyid = 123;
```